# How to make custom Authentication filter like Iauthentication in dotnet core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, authentication, migration

I am migrating asp.net mvc to dotnet 3.1, In older app we are using IAuthorization and IAuthentication filter  now in dotnet 3.1 we have IAuthorization filter but not the IAuthentication.
Kindly suggest the way to make custome Iauthentication filter in dotnet core 3.1.
We are using authentication method OnAuthentication.

```
public void OnAuthentication(AuthenticationContext filterContext)
        {
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.GetString("SUserID") == null && ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authentication"] == "Yes")
            {
                if(!(filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName== "AuthRequest" || filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName == "AuthResponse" || filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName == "Sessiontimeout"))
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Home", action = "AuthRequest", area = string.Empty }));
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the filter like this:

```
  public class CustomAuthorizeFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    { 

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            //check IsAjax request or not
            var ajax = context.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest();

            //IsAuthenticated
            var result = context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

            //check user is in role
            var isInRole = context.HttpContext.User.IsInRole(YourRoleName);

            //get action and  controller Name
            var currentContext = context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext;
            var descriptor = currentContext?.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;
            if (descriptor != null)
            {
                var actionName = descriptor.ActionName;
                var ctrlName = descriptor.ControllerName;
            }

            //and etc
        }
    }
```

you can Authorize your users in **OnActionExecuting** , and for reading session, you can use **HttpContextAccessor**. This is a [good sample](https://cloudstack.ninja/zafeer-ul-haq/accessing-session-values-in-action-filter-in-asp-net-core-3-1/)